# Looping through array, data from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a data model that looks like this.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trans
    has_many :sellers, through: :trans
end

class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customers
    belongs_to :sellers
end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trans
    has_many :customers, through: :trans
end
```

I am trying to create a loop that includes data from all 3 models. This is what I have tried:

```
<%= @seller.trans.sort {|a,b| b.date <=> a.date }.each do |tran| %>
  <li><%= tran %></li>
  <li><%= tran.amount %></li>
  <li><%= tran.date %></li>
<% end %>
```

However, I want to include the name of the Customer as well (which is in a different table) and link to it in the loop that is sorted by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `belongs_to` part of an association must be singular, then you can reference the customer with `tran.customer`.

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

I would also recommend to use the `order(field_name: :desc)` method to sort the records, because that will do the ordering in the database for you.

In the following example, I am assuming that you have a `name` attribute on your `Customer` model. If not, you need to replace it with the link text you want to display.

```
<%= @seller.trans.order(date: :desc) do |tran| %>
  <li><%= tran %></li>
  <li><%= tran.amount %></li>
  <li><%= tran.date %></li>
  <li><%= link_to tran.customer.name, tran.customer %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd fix this (guess it was a typo)

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :seller

end
```

then you should be able to output

```
<%= tran.customer.name %>
```